# How to import and explicitly reference a function correctly

Tags: python, import

I want to serialise a mongoldb cursor. For this, I want to use bson.json_util.dumps. Code example that works:

```
>>> from bson.json_util import dumps
>>> dumps(values)
'[{...}]'
```

However, I am also want to use json.dumps in the same code. For this reason, I would like to explicitly call bson.json_util.dumps:

```
>>> import bson
>>> bson.json_util.dumps(values)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'json_util'
```

This creates an error. I know I can solve my problem by using "import as", but I do not find this a clean solution, and I feel like I am fundamentally missing a point. **Question:** Can anybody explain to me why the second code snippet is not an option?

My best guess is that I have some conflicting modules (one of which pymongo that has bson in it?), so here is my pip freeze output:

```
$ pip freeze
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
pymongo==3.6.1
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bson` is a package. Importing a package does not automatically give you access to its modules; only those modules that are explicitly imported into the package's `__init__.py` are accessible. For everything else, you need to import the module separately.

Note, you could import json_util directly:

```
from bson import json_util
json_util.dumps(...)
```

or, as you mentioned, use `as` to alias the function:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps as bson_dumps
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to test this without having bson installed, but I think the following should work:

```
import bson.json_util
bson.json_util.dumps(values)
```

Comment: I found it difficult to choose which answer to accept. Yours showed me how to run the code that I wanted to run, Daniel's explained to me why what I was doing was not correct. Based on the framing of my question, I accepted Daniel's, but do want to node yours is also highly appreciated.